# Word beginning with "auto" which means "to watch over and over again in mind's eye"

Tags: single-word-requests

I encountered the word I am searching for in R.C.Robertson-Glasgow's Crusoe on Cricket; but, since I do not have the book, nor online access to it, I cannot search for that word.

The meaning is roughly "to watch an act over and over and over again in mind's eye" and in the context he mentioned of a cricket match that can be watched over and over before going to bed.

Any help?

Edit: In response to comments, I checked the list of all the words starting with "auto" and could not find it. If that is the case, then it could be a word, he coined.

Comment: Just a guess: auto-replay?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific in your question. What kind of help are you asking for?

Comment: @Jim If I was any specific, then I would not have asked this question. And the help I require is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: On the one hand, there aren’t many pre-existing verbs that start with *auto-* in [the Dictionary](http://www.oed.com): *autoclave, auto-destruct, autograph, autolithograph, autolyse, automate, autonomize, autopsy, auto-suggest, autotomize, autotype, autoxidize*.  On the other hand, you can always make more of them by prefixing *auto-* to an existing verb, so it was probably one of them (well, unless *autotomize* trips your trigger). It’s pretty hard to guess what you’re needing here.

Comment: @Mahmud - I rewrote your title to express that you are searching for a word beginning with auto. I made a minor change in the first sentence to reflect the same thing. If you disagree with my edit, feel free to revert it.

Comment: In view of the fact that the OP has searched through the list of words beginning with "auto" and did not find the one he was looking for, the question/title could be modified to: "Word which ***might*** begin with "auto" and means....etc." Doesn't roll off the tongue but it reflects more truthfully the context. What does Mahmud think?

Comment: auto-repeat, auto-play, autosuggestion, autoassociation, autocatharsis, autocommunication, autoconstruction, autocontent, ... See: [OneLook](http://onelook.com/?w=auto*&ls=a).

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am left with no choice but to head to university library to actually locate the book and dig it up. If I do so, should I add the answer here or in answer? My current hunch is that he coined it as, at least, shows a snippet of Robertson-Glasgow's biography.

Comment: Oh, please do. I think we all want to know what the word is! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out the word was coined which is why it is difficult to locate. A UCI researcher named Brian Williams was kind enough to find out the word from the actual book. The word is: auto-invigilation.

It is from the 1966 edition of *Crusoe on Cricket: The Cricket Writings of R.C. Robertson-Glasgow* with an introduction by Alan Ross. lan Ross - London, 1966.

"The Art of Watching" begins on page 65 and concludes at page 68.

> "It is not easy to say what precise form of watching cricket gives a
>   man the greatest pleasure, but I think that perhaps the most deep
>   enjoyment is to be derived from what we may term ‘**auto-invigilation**,’
>   the mental going-over, preferably in bed – with no prospect of
>   fielding till after lunch on the next day – of some rare and long
>   desired innings; …”

Comment: Difficult to locate? I'd say, impossible to even imagine such a word. To me the coined expression suggests that the speaker invigilates himself, which is impossible, making sure he doesn't cheat at an exam.

Answer (score 0):

If the context was visualizing something repetitive to help with relaxation before bed, he may have been speaking of [autohypnosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hypnosis).

Answer (score 0):

The person who is re-living the cricket match has put his mind on auto-replay.

> "Chester put his mind on auto-replay, visualizing the cricket match over and over again in his mind."

Answer (score 0):

***autoanalysis***?

similar to self-analysis: v. the process of analyzing oneself. Although the two words could be considered identical the context would clarify the meaning.